# Thompson's Conjecture

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I have heard that the following is a conjecture due to Thompson:
The number of maximal subgroups of a (finite) group $G$ does not exceed the order $|G|$ of the group.

My question is: did Thompson really conjecture this? If so, is there any literature on the subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen this conjecture attributed to Wall (1961), for example: [On a conjecture of G.E. Wall](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~mwl/WALL.PDF). This is a recent article (journal version appeared in 2007), and it gives a bunch of references. The conjecture remains open. Here is a [very recent article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5491) which does not attack the conjecture itself, but uses it as an inspiration for a different conjecture.

Comment: Wall proved it for solvable groups. Another proof (for solvable groups) is given in Pál Hegedűs, The number of maximal subgroups of a solvable group, Publ. Math. Debrecen 78 (2011), no. 3-4, 687–689, MR2867210. Another paper on the solvable case is Benjamin Newton, On the number of maximal subgroups of a finite solvable group, Arch. Math. (Basel) 96 (2011), no. 6, 501–506, MR2821467 (2012f:20092).

Comment: Many thanks for the references.

Comment: @Stefanos Yes, and this holds in greater generality: if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $G_1,G_2$ are subgroups containing $H$, then $G_1/H=G_2/H$ if and only if $G_1=G_2$. Indeed, if there exists $a\in G_1\setminus G_2$, then the coset $aH$ is contained in $G_1/H$ but not in $G_2/H$.

Comment: I only stumbled upon this linking from a different question. It should be noted that Wall's conjecture is false (proved by Frank Luebeck), and counterexamples were found in June 2012, the same time as this answer was written.